# Can we use or open keyboard microphone functionality on button click for getting input?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to use this microphone functionality in my project on click on button action. After click on button starts the microphone.

[image]

Comment: who about implementing and using _SiriKit_?

Comment: @holex actually `SiriKit` is a completely different thing. `SiriKit` is used to integrate your app __into__ Siri. What OP needs is the Speech framework, that is the one used for the dictation feature when the keyboard is visible.

Comment: ...or `AVFoundation` because he stated only intending to use the microphone – and not _what for_; so no one actually knows what OP wants, any idea is a random assumption only.

Comment: @holex i used speech framework and implement voice recognition but i can't able to show when it's stop or how to show recording progress on screen

Comment: i want to show voice signal processing graph on screen when i record voice.

Comment: @AniketLokhande, altogether that would be a kinda _too broad_ question...

Answer (score 2):

The *"microphone"* button on the keyboard uses the [Speech](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech) framework, so you should import and use the `Speech` framework if you need the functionality of the keyboards dictation feature. From documentation:

> iOS users are accustomed to using Siri to interact with apps and—when
>   a keyboard is visible—using dictation to capture their speech. The
>   Speech APIs let you extend and enhance the speech recognition
>   experience within your app, without requiring a keyboard.

Comment: Is there any tutorial for this.

Comment: Hi @David i used AudioPlayer and AudioRecorder for recording and play audio file. Can we convert audio into text at the same time

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, no.

Comment: Thanks @David Pasztor

Comment: Hi @David I have one concern regarding voice recoginition can you help me.

Comment: If you have an unrelated question, ask a new question so that it can help others with the same issue as well.